# Difference between custom control and component in c#(winform)

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

After reading certain sites i came to know the difference between user control and custom control, but now my
question is what is the difference between customcontrol and component other than the namespace hierarchy
Mycustom control -> control -> component and Mycomponent ->component??

both doesnot have designtime support , and doesnot have `Handle` and `Windproc` method? then  what actually they really
differ?

Comment: It is rather a big difference, you can't see a component at runtime and there isn't any way to interact with it since it has no mouse or keyboard events.

Comment: @Hans Passant so what you are saying is component doesnot have runtime UI also compared to custom control. And component will be used for putting controls like Timers.But worst case if i add a component class and if i replaced  the line public partial class testComponent : Component  with public partial class testComponent : RichTextbox, what will be the outcome, again custom and component are same rite?

Comment: If you derive from RichTextBox than you don't have a component, you have a control.  Calling it "testComponent" doesn't make it a component.

Comment: @Hans Passant thats what custom control rite?